# Unity: How to use TextMesh to display Emojis

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, character, symbols, emoticons

I am making a 3D environment in Unity which is designed to retrieve Tweets and display them using Unity's TextMesh. The problem arises when a tweet includes an emoji (emoticons such as  and , which should appear as smiley faces in your browser). 
When a tweet includes one of these characters, unity renders them as either a "?" symbol, or the following symbol in the editor: 
[image: What emoticons look like rendered in the Unity Editor]

...and like this when using a TextMesh:
[image: Emoticons rendered with a TextMesh using Myriad Pro font]

### What Do I Want?

All I need is to represent any smiley/emoticon as character in the TextMesh, using a TTF font. I *don't need* to show a full colour image (like your browser/phone does) of the emoji. I realise that there are some extensions in the Unity store which allow you to do that - TextMesh Pro for example. If there's an easy way of doing this though, it would be better than plain characters.

I am specifically looking to do this using TextMesh, not in any of the new GUI system components.

### Things I've Tried

1. You'd have thought that by downloading a font which contains characters for all of the emoticons you can imagine with their correct encoding, and using this as the font for the TextMesh would solve the problem. This was unfortunately not the case when I tried using Symbola (http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/). This, along with some other fonts rendered the "?" symbol despite having characters for the emoticons being used.

Comment: Maybe you have to create cases for each emoticon (however you represent that in code) and tell Unity to grab the text mesh for that particular emoticon.

Though that seems like it's going to create unnecessarily large amounts of code. I think downloading the text doesn't work because how is it supposed to know one emoticon is the same as the other unless they are represented the same way in the code? Though the may be the exact same emoticon they may not be accessed/represented in the code the same way? Just some thoughts. Not sure how all of this works but hopefully some brainstorming for you

Comment: If you can satisfy yourself and solve you problem using Unity's UI instead of the textmesh you can use Emoji assist (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/53240) with rendering the emoji's from twitter. It also supports rendering the twitter font if you want the emojo's to look exactly like twitter.